# equivalence of null sets for strictly positive density

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a positive measure and $d\tilde{\mu} = w d\mu$ where $w$ is a strictly positive integrable function. In this case how can we show that the two measures have the same null sets?

Comment: I think you mean $d\tilde{\mu} = wd\mu$ ?

Comment: @Jakobian Yes my mistake.

Comment: Well, $d\mu = w^{-1} d\tilde{\mu}$ then, the situation is symmetric. Just prove that if a set is null for $\mu$, then it's null for $\tilde{\mu}$